# What is the fastest way read slice from hdf5 dataset using h5py?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have h5-file with dataset with dimensions 280000x62 and dtype float32. I need to read just 1 column, for example number 0. I do it with following code:

```
def read_data_from_datasets(file_path, group_name, dataset_name, slice_in_np=False, tries_cnt=3):

    with h5py.File(file_path, "r") as file:

        time_sum = 0.
        for i in range(tries_cnt):
            start = perf_counter()
            h5_group = file[group_name]
            if slice_in_np:
                dataset = h5_group[dataset_name][:]
                np_arr_sliced = dataset[:, 0]
            else:
                dataset = h5_group[dataset_name][:, 0]
                np_arr_sliced = dataset[:]

            end = perf_counter()
            time_sum += end - start
        print('time for reading dataset = %s' % (time_sum / tries_cnt))
```

This operation took in average 0.0138 sec. However if I copy this column to new dataset with dimension 280000x1 (2-dimensions dataset with 1 column) and read it with same function it will take 0.0006 sec, i.e. about 20 times faster

Is there a way to reach same-order speed with slicing 1 column from 62-columns dataset as just reading 1 column from 1-column dataset? Or I have to create separate dataset for each column?

Comment: Some options: 1. Transpose the array before writing. Reading a single row is very fast compared to a single column. 2. [Create a chunked dataset](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage) with chunk dimensions `[1, N]`. Option 2, especially the choice of `N` depends on what you plan to do with the file. Is reading a column the only/predominant access pattern, or do you need rowwise access? Or blocks, column segments, etc.?

Comment: @Homer512 reading column is only pattern i need. Thanks, i will try chunk and report back result

Comment: If you are reading data of shape of `[:,1`], you want to set `chunks=(N0,1)` (not `=(1, N1)`). I created 3 datasets to test. Dataset 1 has no chunks, time to read = 0.0333 sec. Dataset 2 has `chunks=(1,62)`, time to read = 2.8519 sec. Dataset 3 has `chunks=(280000,1)`, time to read = 0.0011.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no you don't need to write a separate dataset for each column of data.

I/O performance depends on a lot of parameters. You didn't say how you created the data. Did you use chunking and/or compression on the datasets? If you don't know, you can check with `print(file[group_name][dataset_name].chunks)`. For now, I will assume NO since this is a small dataset. However, chunk shape/size will affect read performance, especially on very large datasets.

Also, a note on your code. This line of code creates an array (e.g., reads the dataset data into a NumPy array.) It DOES NOT create a dataset. That means you have an in-memory copy of the data.

```
dataset = h5_group[dataset_name][:]
```

The difference in I/O performance between `slice_in_np=False` and `True` comes down to the difference in reading 1 column(`False`) and reading the entire dataset  (`True`) into an array:

```
if slice_in_np: #True 
   # this reads the entire dataset to an array
    dataset = h5_group[dataset_name][:]
    # this reads a slice of the array to a new array
    np_arr_sliced = dataset[:, 0]            
else: #False
   # this reads a slice of the dataset to an array
   dataset = h5_group[dataset_name][:, 0] 
   # this the entire array to a new array
   np_arr_sliced = dataset[:]
```

In general, reading the slice is faster than reading the entire dataset. You can improve this slightly by reading the slice directly to the array as shown below.

```
else: #False
   # this reads a slice of the dataset to the desired array
   np_arr_sliced = h5_group[dataset_name][:, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer demonstrates the performance influence of different read methods on I/O performance:

- Reading unchunked data Column wise vs Row wise
- Unchunked vs Chunked datasets
- Column vs Row chunk shape (for column wise reading)

As @Homer512 mentioned, reading row wise is faster than column wise. Also, chunked I/O is faster than unchunked I/O (if chunk shape is set properly). That said, chunking is more helpful for column wise reads (vs row wise). Finally, improperly setting chunk shape can have a dramatic negative affect on I/O performance.

Summary of tests and results:

| Test / Dataset | Description | Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| no_chunks | Read column wise (OP) | 0.0316 |
| transpose | Transpose and read row wise | 0.0010 |
| col_chunks | Read column wise w/ column chunk shape | 0.0010 |
| transpose_c | Transpose and read row wise w/ row chunk shape | 0.0010 |
| row_chunks | Read column wise w/ row chunk shape | 2.9320 |

Code below creates the file with the 5 datasets above, then reads each dataset as described. Timing data is averaged over 5 reads of each dataset.

```
n0, n1 = 280000, 62 
arr = np.arange(n0*n1).reshape(n0, n1)
with h5py.File(file_path,'w') as h5f:
    grp = h5f.create_group(group_name)
    dataset_name = "no_chunks"
    grp.create_dataset(dataset_name, data=arr)
    dataset_name = "transpose"
    grp.create_dataset(dataset_name, data=arr.transpose())
    dataset_name = "col_chunks"
    grp.create_dataset(dataset_name, data=arr, chunks=(n0,1))
    dataset_name = "transpose_c"
    grp.create_dataset(dataset_name, data=arr.transpose(), chunks=(1,n0))
    dataset_name = "row_chunks"
    grp.create_dataset(dataset_name, data=arr, chunks=(1,n1))
    
tries_cnt = 5
ds_name_list = ["no_chunks", "transpose", "col_chunks", "transpose_c", "row_chunks"]

with h5py.File(file_path, "r") as file:
    for ds_name in ds_name_list:
        time_sum = 0.
        for i in range(tries_cnt):
            start = perf_counter()
            if "transpose" not in ds_name:
                arr = file[group_name][ds_name][:,0]
            else:
                arr = file[group_name][ds_name][0,:]
            end = perf_counter()
            time_sum += end - start    
        print(f'time for reading {ds_name} dataset = {(time_sum/tries_cnt):.4f}')
```